# What should I add/remove in this code, in order to receive the correct data from Dynamo and Lex?

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have a lambda function that I wrote to receive data from Amazon Lex, that when triggered, will go to a DynamoDB that I have, and will query the Table for the information provided through Lex. However, at the moment I cannot get the query to work, as it doesn't show up the results I am looking for. How do I get the information gathered through lex, and match what they said to some information in Dynamo? (the dynamodb has a list of over 400 possible items they can choose from, a LOT of them are similar)

I tried a scan, and that did not work for what I need it for. It would not give the correct data that was given in the test parameter.

```
'use strict';

const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const dynamo = new aws.DynamoDB();

module.exports.handler = function(intentRequest, context, callback) {
  console.log(intentRequest);
  dynamo.query({
    TableName:'ServiceOfferings',
    KeyConditionExpression: '#name = :searchName',
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
      "#name": "name",
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":searchName":{"S":"PCC"} //PCC is an example of what i need searched through lex. That value needs to be dynamic.
    }
  },(err, data)=>{
    console.log(data);
    callback(err, data);
  });
};
```

Here is the response i receive from the test parameter:

```
Response:
{
  "Items": [],
  "Count": 0,
  "ScannedCount": 0
}

Request ID:
"ca1d95ce-161e-487d-8ca5-db80d5799724"

Function Logs:
START RequestId: ca1d95ce-161e-487d-8ca5-db80d5799724 Version: $LATEST
2019-10-03T14:59:00.139Z    ca1d95ce-161e-487d-8ca5-db80d5799724    INFO    { 'dialog-state': 'ReadyForFulfillment',
  'input-transcript': 'PCC',
  slots: { list: 'PCC' },
  'intent-name': 'getServiceOffering' }
2019-10-03T14:59:00.899Z    ca1d95ce-161e-487d-8ca5-db80d5799724    INFO    { Items: [], Count: 0, ScannedCount: 0 }
END RequestId: ca1d95ce-161e-487d-8ca5-db80d5799724
REPORT RequestId: ca1d95ce-161e-487d-8ca5-db80d5799724  Duration: 1034.16 ms    Billed Duration: 1100 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 92 MB  Init Duration: 414.90 ms
```

Comment: can you try with ":searchName":"PCC" ?

Comment: That comes back with validation error that says "Unexpected Key 0/1/2" (length of PCC)

Comment: then try with DocumentClient() instead of DynamoDB() https://egkatzioura.com/2016/07/02/query-dynamodb-items-with-node-js/

Comment: Parameter type does not match schema type

Comment: did you use ":searchName":{"S":"PCC"} or ":searchName":"PCC" after changing to DocumentClient()?

Comment: Still no results. No error, but no results

Comment: maybe share a screenshot of your table (from web console)?

Comment: I cannot add a screenshot, but if it helps, the table columns consist of "name", "business_criticality", etc... and the listings under the "name" column are in quotations. (the primary key field is a string)

Comment: you can add here https://imgur.com/upload?beta But anyway, I think the quotations are the issue, as the key your are searching does not appear in the table. Try ":searchName":"\"PCC\"" or ":searchName":"\\"PCC\\""

Comment: That worked perfectly. thank you. i didnt think the quotes mattered but im happy that was the fix.

Comment: No problem, let me put that into an answer

Answer (score 0):

Replace `":searchName":{"S":"PCC"}` with `":searchName":"\"PCC\""` (considering the quotes of the hash key)

You also should fix the data entry on the hash key btw, leaving the ExpressionAttributeValues to `":searchName":"PCC"`